# can't start service linux 18.06

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services

How can I start this service? What I'm trying to do is running a `symfony4` command this file is created on /lib/systemd/system/file.service

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -ce \
"/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/Documents/symfony/bin/console \ 
app:worker:payroll-parser -v"
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A systemd unit file is an old Microsoft Windows .INI file.  Values in .INI files are not *(key,value)* tuples.  .INI files have section headings.  They are *(section,key,value)* tuples.  The several appropriate section headings are documented in the `systemd.unit` and `systemd.service` user manual pages.

Moreover, using process substitution and the `tee` command is superfluous given that standard output and standard error already go to the journal, and that the `StandardOutput` setting exists.

Comment: Already modified my service and updated errors